# how to fix list out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data inside a text file:

```
A, 2, 1500
B, 5, 2000
C, 8, 2500
D, 10, 4000
E, 12, 4800
F, 18, 5300
```

And I have this program which it print error list out of range:

```
def readfile(fname):
    txt = open(fname)
    txt1 = txt.read()
    new_list = []
    for i in txt1:
        split = i.split(',  ')
        new_list.append({'Car': split[0], 'Seat': int(split[1]), 'cost': int(split[2])})
readfile('car.txt')
```

Any suggestion and how to fix it...Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual cause of your error is that you're calling `text.read()` (when you should've been calling `text.readlines()`. You then end up iterating over each character!

You can use an `if` check to test the contents of the line before creating the dictionary and appending it to your list.

```
def readfile(fname):
    c = ['Car', 'Seat', 'Cost']
    new_list = []

    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                new_list.append(dict(zip(c, i.split(',  '))))

    return new_list
```

---

Other nitpicks -

- Use `with...as` when opening files so you don't have to call `file.close`
- `dict` + `zip` will prevent the need to hardcode your list indexing.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the previous poster. When you call txt.read(), Python is reading the entire file into a string called `txt1`. Your for loop is then iterating over every **character** in the string. Thus, on the first iteration, `i` only contains the character `A`. This means that when trying to call `split()` on the single character, a single item is returned and the length of the returned list is 1. When you evaluate `split[1]`, you are indexing beyond the end of the returned list and Python raises an index out of bounds error.

To fix this, try the `readlines()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you postet is the EXACT copy - then your mistake is here:

```
split = i.split(',  ')
```

You used two spaces after your comma instead of one and your split method doesn't cut your input string (which has only one space after each comma)